# How do I confirm that nginx aio is working on FreeBSD?

Tags: nginx, freebsd

I have nginx configured with

```
aio   on;
```

and no special prep on the OS side.

I tested loading lots of small jpegs from multiple clients, but there was not much of a different between aio on and aio off.

I'm not sure if I need to enable AIO in the kernel or not. How can I confirm whether nginx aio is working or not on FreeBSD? What would happen if nginx was configured to use aio but the FreeBSD kernel did not support it?

I'm using FreeBSD 8.1 and nginx 1.2.7 and the filesystem is UFS

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if I need to enable AIO in the kernel or not.

Yes, you have to either link statically:

```
options VFS_AIO
```

or load dynamically:

```
kldload aio
```

Then you can verify by running:

```
strings -n3 /boot/kernel/kernel | sed -n 's/^__//p' | grep aio
kldstat -m aio
```

Comment: "strings -n3 /boot/kernel/kernel | sed -n 's/^__//p' | grep aio" didn't return anything. "kldstat -m aio" returned "Id  Refs Name\n  4    1 aio". Does this mean aio is setup properly? Is it normal for the first command to not return anything?

Comment: The output of second command indicate that the `aio` module is loaded dynamically. Have you disabled [`sendfile`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#sendfile)?